# How to query duplicate records which have been inserted more than 2 times within 5 minutes, have the same email address and status = 1?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

I have my sample data in the database table as following.

```
id   email            created_at              status
1    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:01:30      1
2    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:02:20     -1
3    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:03:30      1
4    new@mail.com     2016-01-01 01:04:00      1
5    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:04:30      1
6    new@mail.com     2016-01-01 02:59:08      1
7    new@mail.com     2016-01-01 03:01:24      1
8    iii@mail.com     2016-12-24 04:20:30      1
9    iii@mail.com     2016-12-24 04:23:29     -2
10   new@mail.com     2016-12-24 04:24:08      1
11   iii@mail.com     2016-12-24 04:25:29      1
12   new@mail.com     2016-12-24 04:32:08      1
13   e@mail.com       2016-12-24 05:16:30      1
14   iii@mail.com     2016-12-24 06:00:00      1
15   aa@email.com     2017-07-17 15:03:00      1
16   aa@email.com     2017-07-17 15:04:00      1
17   aa@email.com     2017-07-17 15:08:01      1
```

My requirements are:

```
a. Records are duplicated by email
b. The duplicated records are more than 2, thus 3 and upper
c. Those 3 or upper duplicated records have been inserted within 5 minutes Interval.
d. status = 1
```

Below is my sql query, provided by @Strawberry.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
       FROM my_table a
       JOIN 
          ( SELECT x.* 
                 , MAX(y.created_at) AS range_end
              FROM my_table x
              JOIN my_table y
                ON y.email = x.email
               AND y.id >= x.id 
               AND y.created_at <= x.created_at + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
             GROUP
                BY x.id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
          ) b
         ON b.email = a.email 
        AND a.created_at BETWEEN b.created_at AND b.range_end;
```

The above query returns the following records.

```
id   email            created_at              status
1    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:01:30      1
2    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:02:20     -1
3    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:03:30      1
5    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:04:30      1
8    iii@mail.com     2016-12-24 04:20:30      1
9    iii@mail.com     2016-12-24 04:23:29     -2
11   iii@mail.com     2016-12-24 04:25:29      1
```

I tried to put `"WHERE status = 1"` to get the following records only, because they meet my requirements.

```
id   email            created_at             status
1    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:01:30     1
3    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:03:30     1
5    e@mail.com       2016-01-01 01:04:30     1
```

What I want to retrieve are the records that are duplicated by same email address, they have been inserted more than 2 times within 5 minutes and their status is 1. How to `"WHERE status = 1"` to get my desired result?

Answer (score 1):

I think your query is a bit too complicated for MySQL:

```
select t.*
from my_table t join
     my_table t2
     on t.email = t2.email and
        t2.created_at > t.created_at and
        t2.created_at <= date_add(t.created_at, interval 5 minute) and
        t2.status = 1
where t.id = 1
group by t.id
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Because `id` is unique in your table, it is okay to `group by` that column and select other columns from the table.  In fact, this use of the MySQL extension is even consistent with ANSI standard SQL.

Comment: Looks like the 5 minute interval is missing in `<=` and it should be `having count(*) >= 2`

Comment: @BrakNicku . . . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
       FROM service_request a
       JOIN 
          ( SELECT x.* 
                 , MAX(y.created_at) AS range_end
              FROM service_request x
              JOIN service_request y
                ON y.email = x.email
               AND y.id >= x.id 
               AND y.status = x.status
               AND y.created_at <= x.created_at + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
             WHERE x.status = 1 
             GROUP
                BY x.id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
          ) b
         ON b.email = a.email 
        AND a.created_at BETWEEN b.created_at AND b.range_end;
```